# Could the output label in turn with the text?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am new in NLP.
On Pytorch, I'm training BertForSequenceClassification for a multi-label task.
Is it possible for the output label to match the text?

nput is a text like : name, phon, address，output : label_name, label_phone, label_address.

In this case, input : phon, address, name，output : label_name, label_phone, label_address.

However, I'd like the output to look something like this: label_phone, label_address, label_name.

Is there anything I can change?

```
## Package
# PyTorch
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.dataset import random_split
import torch.utils.data as data
# BERT Related Libraries
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
# Python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# ML Parameters
epoch = 8
device = 'cuda'
num_labels = 9
batch_size = 32
epsilon = 1e-8
learning_rate = 5e-5

## Define model
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=num_labels)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr = learning_rate, eps = epsilon, weight_decay = 1e-2)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size = 1, gamma=0.1, last_epoch=-1)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

train_losses = []
train_acces = []
val_losses = []
val_acces = []


## Train with training set 
def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion, device):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    for batch_idx, (sentences, labels) in enumerate(iterator):

        # tokenize the sentences
        encoding = tokenizer(sentences, return_tensors='pt', padding=True, truncation=True)
        input_ids = encoding['input_ids']
        attention_mask = encoding['attention_mask']

        # generate prediction
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)  # NOT USING INTERNAL CrossEntropyLoss
        
        # compute gradients and update weights
        loss = criterion(outputs.logits, labels) # BCEWithLogitsLoss has sigmoid
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # accumulate train loss
        train_loss += loss.item()

        # record processed data count
        prob = outputs.logits.sigmoid()
        total += (labels.size(0)*labels.size(1))
        # take the index of the highest prob as prediction output
        THRESHOLD = 0.7
        prediction = prob.detach().clone()
        prediction[prediction > THRESHOLD] = 1
        prediction[prediction <= THRESHOLD] = 0
        correct += prediction.eq(labels).sum().item()
    
    train_acc = correct/total
    print('train_loss: %f\t' % (train_loss))
    print('train_acc: %f\t' % (train_acc))
    return train_loss, train_acc


## Validate with testing set 
def test(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion, device):
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (sentences, labels) in enumerate(iterator):

            # tokenize the sentences
            encoding = tokenizer(sentences, return_tensors='pt', padding=True, truncation=True)
            input_ids = encoding['input_ids']
            attention_mask = encoding['attention_mask']
            
            # generate prediction
            outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
            
            loss = criterion(outputs.logits, labels)
            val_loss += loss.item()

            # record processed data count
            prob = outputs.logits.sigmoid()
            total += (labels.size(0)*labels.size(1))
            # take the index of the highest prob as prediction output
            THRESHOLD = 0.7
            prediction = prob.detach().clone()
            prediction[prediction > THRESHOLD] = 1
            prediction[prediction <= THRESHOLD] = 0
            correct += prediction.eq(labels).sum().item()
    
    val_acc = correct/total
    print('val_loss: %f\t' % (val_loss))
    print('val_acc: %f\t' % (val_acc))
    print('correct: %i , total: %i' % (correct, total))
    return val_loss, val_acc


for e in range(epoch):
    
    print("===== Epoch %i =====" % e)

    print("Training started ...")
    train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, device)
    train_losses.append(train_loss/len(train_loader))
    train_acces.append(train_acc/len(train_loader))

    # validation testing
    print("Testing started ...")
    val_loss, val_acc = test(model, test_loader, optimizer, criterion, device)
    val_losses.append(val_loss/len(test_loader))
    val_acces.append(val_acc/len(test_loader))

    scheduler.step()
```

If you need more information,please let me konw.
Thanks for all.

Comment: Which library/model is this? To a network, it does not matter what the output means. As long as you are calculating the loss correctly, you should be good.

Comment: @Bhupen Hi, thank for reply. The model is Bert and the lossfuntion is nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss. I edited code. are there any suggestions for loss?